# Is it possible to have a generic function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters?

Tags: generics, rust, variadic-functions

I know that rust does not have variadics. And I know that macros are one possible way to emulate them. However, I am interested in how traits can be used for this purpose.

For example, the Bevy ECS system can take functions with arbitrary parameter combinations in their signature, provided the arguments implement a given trait.

I would like to better understand how this mechanism works.

Comment: They probably take not _arbitrary_ combinations, but arbitrary combinations _up to some limit_. Can't check it right now, but if this is the case, one can simply implement some trait for functions with 0, 1, ... N arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually an arbitrary number of type parameters; Rust does not support this (yet). The most common solution is to use a macro to generate implementations for a number of type parameters up to some fixed limit. For instance, `Reflect` is implemented for up to 12 type parameters via a `macro_rules!` macro [here](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/fe777d5c3fba64bec250b8ced3a6ba98fbd07a64/crates/bevy_reflect/src/tuple.rs#L617). This is also common throughout the stdlib, which also uses it (for instance, [to implement `From<(T, ..., T)> for [T; N]` and vice versa](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/tuple.rs.html#360), for `N` at most 12).